# Deriving a heat equation solution in a form of power series

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have read in a book [Formal Power Series and Linear Systems of Meromorphic Ordinary Differential Equations](https://books.google.pl/books?id=OB8RBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR9&lpg=PR9&dq=getting%20power%20series%20from%20heat%20equation&source=bl&ots=PKiNyo_Eps&sig=ACfU3U0UxJP4uE7b10WOgmkW2hEthgZVlw&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5mc--7-LpAhX2ZxUIHVDkDPIQ6AEwD3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=getting%20power%20series%20from%20heat%20equation&f=false) that it is possible to formally derive a solution to heat equation in a form of power series. The fragment of this book is in the picture below.

[image]

Unfortunately there is only the result without the method of deriving it. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can derive this by making the "ansatz"

\begin{equation}u(t,x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_n(x)t^n \end{equation}
Using the initial condition, this immediately implies $u(0,x)=u_0(x)=\varphi(x)$.
Formally(!) differentiating the power series yields
\begin{align}
u_t(t,x)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n(x)nt^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)u_{n+1}(x)t^n\\
u_{xx}(t,x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n''(x)t^n
\end{align}
Using the equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ and comparing the coefficients of the power series expansion leads to
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}(x)(n+1)=u_n''(x)
\end{align}
In the case $n=0$ this reduces to
\begin{align}
u_1(x)=u_0''(x)=\varphi''(x)
\end{align}
Inductively we get
\begin{align}
u_n(x)=\frac{\varphi^{(2n)}(x)}{n!}
\end{align}